# Join matrices with same values in different vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, merge

I am trying to merge two matrices that share same values in multiple columns.

The following matrices should exemplify my problem and provide a MWE. However, my data is very long `size(500000, 4)`, therefore I am searching an efficient way to merge them. The data consists of option data where `c` are call and `p` put data, with columns `1:4`: date, strike, expiry, bid-price. In the end I would like to have matrix with columns `1:5`: date, strike, expiry, call-bid-price, put-bid-price. As shown in the MWE, the data is not of same length, but each combination of the columns `1:3` (date, strike, expiry) only exists once.

`c = [7356011 300 7356081 1.15;
     7356011 400 7356081 1.56;
     7356011 500 7356081 1.79;
     7356011 300 7356088 1.25;
     7356011 400 7356088 1.67;
     7356011 500 7356088 1.89;
     7356011 600 7356088 1.92;
     7356012 300 7356081 0.79;
     7356012 400 7356081 0.99;
     7356012 500 7356081 1.08;
     7356012 300 7356088 0.81;
     7356012 400 7356088 0.90;
     7356012 500 7356088 1.07]`

`p = [7356011 300 7356081 1.35;
     7356011 400 7356081 1.15;
     7356011 500 7356081 1.03;
     7356011 300 7356088 1.56;
     7356011 400 7356088 1.15;
     7356011 500 7356088 1.03;
     7356012 300 7356081 1.25;
     7356012 400 7356081 1.19;
     7356012 500 7356081 1.02;
     7356012 300 7356088 1.14;
     7356012 400 7356088 0.98;
     7356012 500 7356088 0.76;
     7356012 600 7356088 0.56;
     7356012 700 7356088 0.44]`

I tried to build an ID for each column, by using `strcat` and `num2str`, and getting 'ID(1) = 73560113007356081' however this takes very long for the large amount of data. I have also tried to find a solution using, `unique` and `ismember`, but had trouble with the multiple columns.

Wished output would be:

`7356011 300 7356081 1.15 1.35
 7356011 400 7356081 1.56 1.15
 7356011 500 7356081 1.79 1.03
 7356011 300 7356088 1.25 1.56
 7356011 400 7356088 1.67 1.15
 7356011 500 7356088 1.89 1.03
 7356011 600 7356088 1.92 NaN
 7356012 300 7356081 0.79 1.25
 7356012 400 7356081 0.99 1.19
 7356012 500 7356081 1.08 1.02
 7356012 300 7356088 0.81 1.14
 7356012 400 7356088 0.90 0.98
 7356012 500 7356088 1.07 0.76
 7356012 600 7356088  NaN 0.56
 7356012 700 7356088  NaN 0.44`

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why does your desired matrix have NaNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop, use `intersect` instead.

```
[~,ic,ip] = intersect(c(:, 1:3),p(:, 1:3),'rows');
m = [c(ic, :), p(ip,end)];
```

Edit:
If you want to include `NaN`s where they don't intersect like the above poster.

```
function m = merge(c, p, nc, np)
    %check for input arg errors
    if nargin == 3
        np = nc;
    elseif nargin ~= 4
        disp('Please enter either 3 or 4 arguments')
        m = {};
        return
    end

    %make sure they are shaped the same
    nc = reshape(nc, 1, []);
    np = reshape(np, 1, []);

    %And have the same number of elements
    if numel(nc) ~= numel(np)
        disp('Please ensure arguments 3 and 4 have the same number of elements')
        m = {};
        return
    end

    %The columns that aren't being compared
    NotNC = find(~ismember(1:size(c,2), nc));
    NotNP = find(~ismember(1:size(p,2), np));

    %Find the matching rows
    [matches,ic,ip] = intersect(c(:, nc),p(:, np),'rows');

    %Put together matching rows with the other data not included in the match
    m1 = [matches, c(ic, NotNC), p(ip, NotNP)];

    %Find rows that did not matched
    NotIC = find(~ismember(1:size(c,1), ic));
    NotIP = find(~ismember(1:size(p,1), ip));

    %Put together data not in the matched set
    m2 = [c(NotIC, nc), c(NotIC, NotNC), nan(length(NotIC), size(NotNP,2))];
    m3 = [p(NotIP, np), nan(length(NotIP), size(NotNC,2)), p(NotIP, NotNP)];

    %merge all three lists
    m = [m1; m2; m3];

end
```

Comment: This is significantly faster than Samuel's post. 'tic ; merge(a, b, 1:3) ; toc', 
'Elapsed time is 0.048150 seconds.'
'tic ; Samuel(a, b) ; toc'
'Elapsed time is 8.432094 seconds.'

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also to @SamuelNLP Worked also fine, however due to the quantity of data I prefer above solution!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did not understand if p is always bigger so I'll write the two solutions with an `if`.

```
if length(c) > length(p)
    xx = length(c);
    newm = [c NaN(xx, 1)];
    row = ismember(c, p, 'rows');

    newm(row, end) = p(row, end);
else
    xx = length(p);
    newm = [p(:,1:3) NaN(xx, 1) p(:, end)];

    row = ismember(p(:,1:3), c(:,1:3), 'rows');

    newm(row, 4) = c(row, end);
end
```

UPDATE:

this code works for your present example.

```
[row_p, row_c] = ismember(p(:,1:3), c(:,1:3), 'rows');

newm = [];

for ii = 1:length(row_p)
    if row_p(ii) == 1
        newm = [newm; p(ii, 1:3) c(row_c(ii), end) p(ii, end)];
    else
        newm = [newm; p(ii, 1:3) NaN p(ii, end)];
    end
end

[row_c, row_p] = ismember(c(:,1:3), p(:,1:3), 'rows');

for ii = 1:length(row_c)
    if row_c(ii) == 1
        newm = [newm; c(ii, 1:3) c(ii, end) p(row_p(ii), end)];
    else
        newm = [newm; c(ii, 1:3) c(ii, end) NaN];
    end
end

newm = unique(newm, 'rows');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The `if` statement is great, since the matrices `c` and `p` sometimes differ in lengths
However, how could I solve this problem, if I additionally have a row in `c` that is not in `p` and vice versa. I edited the example to show what I mean. Since now, It is not possible to choose a matric as base matrix that is filled with the other. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `7356012 700 7356088  NaN 0.44` is supposed to be last row?

Comment: I don't understand the `NaN`in `7356011 600 7356088 1.92 NaN`.

Comment: my option data consists of more rows, this is just the MWE. However the columns are the same as shown. It is not important for me, that it is the last row, but more, that the values are matched if the same values are present in `c` as well as `p` and if not a `NaN` for the missing value is shown.
Should the matrix be of identical length and every column `1:3` combination (date, strike, expiry) in `c` is also present in `p` no `NaN`s should be returned. However, I have several of these option matrices and some have the same amount of options (rows) and others don't.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your second comment. The `NaN` in `7356011 600 7356088 1.92 NaN` comes from the fact, that there is only a call option with strike `600` on date `7356011` with expiry `7356088`, but no put. 
The `NaN` in the last two rows, are due to the fact of missing call options for strikes `600` and `700` with date `7356012` and expiry `7356088`

Comment: I do not mind, if the row `7356011 600 7356088 1.92 NaN` is not at that specified position, it could also be last. The merging is more important